# Number of distinct elements of std::unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, unordered-multiset

I need a data structure that is able to store elements along with their frequencies. Additionally, I need to be able to find efficiently how many distinct elements I currently have. I was looking into `std::unordered_multiset` since I can insert each element and then by simply invoking the `count(key)` method I am able to find the frequency of an element.

I was expecting that when I would invoke the `size()` method of `std::unordered_multiset` I would be able to get the total number of distinct elements in the set. Though, that seems to not be the case and the total number of inserted elements is returned.

How could I find the total number of distinct elements in `std::unordered_multiset`. Would an `std::unordered_map` be preferred for this specific use case?

Comment: Yes, a `map` would be appropriate here.

Comment: Just have an `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` storing each distinct key and its frequency as its value.

Comment: For a frequency counter or histogram type of calculations I would definitely recommend `std::unordered_map` instead of a multiset.

Comment: What would then be a suitable use case for using `std::unordered_multiset`?